# Sum in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

My Query is

```
select count(*) as cnt,
       EXTRACT(day FROM current_date - min(txdate))::int as days,

       sum (Select opening from acledgerbal l 
              where acname='Arv' 
              union all 
              Select sum(v2.debit-v2.credit) as opening from acvoucher2 v2 where
              txdate<='05/03/2014') as opening

from acduebills acb,acledger l 

where (acb.opening+acb.debit-acb.credit) > 0 
   and acb.unitname='Sales' 
   and l.acname='Arv' 
   and l.acno=acb.acno
```

Here it show  `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` Error. 
How do using sum for the subquery.

**I'm using postgresql 9.1**

EDIT:

I want to get count of rows in `acduebills` tables which is (acb.opening+acb.debit-acb.credit) > 0  and acb.unitname='Sales'. After that I want to get difference of day which is minimum date in same condition. After that I want to get opening, which comes from two tables: `acledgerbal` and `acvoucher2`. `acvoucher` is table checked by the `txdate` condition.

How to get those detail in single query?. How to get Same details in multiple schema's?

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `.. from acvoucher2 v2, txdate<='05/03/2014' `, probably missing `where` clause, please check the query.

Comment: This is broken in multiple places. And you are not providing enough information to fix it

Comment: Much better now. `txdate` is of type `date`? And from which table? How are `acduebills` and `acledger` connected?

Comment: sir `txdate` type is `date`. and `acduebills` and `acledger` connected with `acno`. `acno` is `primary key` in `acledger`, `foreign key` in `acduebills`. `l.acno=acb.acno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
     , current_date - min(txdate)::date AS days   -- subtract dates directly

     , (SELECT round(sum(opening)::numeric, 2)
        FROM  (
           SELECT opening
           FROM   acledgerbal
           WHERE  acname = 'Arv' 

           UNION ALL
           SELECT debit - credit
           FROM   acvoucher2
           WHERE  txdate <= '2014-05-03'
           ) sub
       ) AS opening
FROM   acduebills b
JOIN   acledger   l USING (acno)
WHERE ((b.opening + b.debit) - b.credit) > 0 
AND    b.unitname ='Sales' 
AND    l.acname = 'Arv';
```

[`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) to decimal places only works with type `numeric`, so I cast the sum.

Comment: Sir i edit my question. can you get any information. sorry for my english

Comment: @SATSON: Added a bit more.

Comment: how to get differents only in numeric value like 2

Comment: sir i asked. the current_date - txdate return 2 days. but i want to 2 only.

Comment: If `txdate` is type is `date` (as you commented) you get an `integer`, not an `interval`. Is `txdate` a `timestamp`, not a `date`? Then you need to cast or use your original calculation.

Comment: thanks sir. I have one doubt sir. how to get those details using multiple schema. Can you ask other question for multiple schems's

Comment: @SATSON: Sorry, I don't understand. Start a *new question* with explanation & example. You can link to this question for context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here in the following statement:

```
   sum (  Select opening from acledgerbal l 
          where acname='Arv' 
          union all 
          Select sum(v2.debit-v2.credit) as opening from acvoucher2 v2,
          txdate<='05/03/2014' )
```

You use UNION so this subquery returns at least 2 rows. So you get an error that subquery can't return more than one row: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Try to change it to:

```
   (Select SUM(opening) from acledgerbal l WHERE acname='Arv')
   +  
   (Select SUM(v2.debit-v2.credit) as opening from acvoucher2 v2 
                                           WHERE txdate<='05/03/2014')
```